# VS 2013 Losing a Decimal When Writing to Access

Tags: visual-studio-2013, decimal, ms-access-2013

I'm writing a variable dimensioned as Decimal to an Access DB.  The value calculated is 1600.91.  The field in Access is set to:  Field Size - Decimal, Format - Fixed, Precision - 12,  Scale - 2, Decimal Places - 2

But the number that ends up in the table is 1600.90.  Even if I hard-code the variable to 1600.91, Access shows 1600.90.  Other rows in that column have both decimals showing correctly.

The setup for the Access connection is as follows:

```
Public con As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\SPJ_CRVM.accdb")

Public daAnswer As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [answer]", con)
Public cbAnswer = New OleDbCommandBuilder(daAnswer)
Public dtAnswer As New DataTable
Public drAnswer As DataRow

cbAnswer.quoteprefix = "["
cbAnswer.quotesuffix = "]"
daAnswer.Fill(dtAnswer)

drAnswer = dtAnswer.NewRow()
```

The code is as follows:

```
Dim ldec_gmp as Decimal

ldec_gmp = Math.Round(NUM / PVP * 12 / M, 4, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
drAnswer("guar_maturity_premium") = ldec_gmp
```

And writing to Access is done here:

```
dtAnswer.Rows.Add(drAnswer)
daAnswer.Update(dtAnswer)
```

Update:

NUM & PVP are both dimensioned as Decimal; M is dimensioned at Integer

In the example row:

NUM = 41506.813854184606481174528411

PVP = 25.927068677092090950619294386

M = 12

ldec_gmp = 1600.9065 with MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero set to 4

ldec_gmp = 1600.91 with MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero set to 2

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Data type _Decimal_ is known to have some oddities. Try changing the data type of the field to _Currency_.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include a [mcve] to illustrate the problem? In particular: (1) Are you using OleDb, or Odbc? (2) Are you performing the update using a literal SQL command? ... a parameterized query? ... a DataAdapter update? ... ?

Comment: Thanks, Gord.  Please let me know if I left something out.

Comment: It looks like you are rounding to 4 decimal places. Does the calculated value come out to *exactly* 1600.9100? If not then you may find that the numbers get truncated (instead of rounded) when saving to a field with fewer decimal places.

Comment: True, it is set to 4 decimal places at the moment.  It was originally set to 2, which was giving me 1600.90 at the table; then I added the MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero and still gave me 1600.90.  The rounding to 4 was just my latest attempt.

Comment: Can you provide the actual values for `NUM`, `PVP`, and `M` that will recreate the issue?

Comment: Also, please show how those variables were declared (`Dim`'d), i.e., as `Decimal`, `Double`, or whatever.

Comment: Sorry for the delay - holidays.  Update above.

Comment: I am unable to recreate your issue. The VB.NET console application I used for testing is [here](http://pastebin.com/0ff7kbyN). It works fine when rounding to two (2) decimal places, although it *will* truncate to 1600.90 when `ldec_gmp` is rounded to 4 decimal places instead of 2.

Comment: The code does work in VB.NET; it is in Visual Studio Express 2013 where this occurs.  I'm very sorry - I thought I included that.

Comment: *"it is in Visual Studio Express 2013 where [the issue] occurs"* - In what part of Visual Studio? VB.NET is a component of Visual Studio, along with C# and other stuff.

Comment: Sorry again.  I associate VB.NET with what is actually version 7 (2002).  The code is in Visual Basic 2013 of Visual Studio 2013 Express.

Comment: The test code linked in my earlier comment was written and tested in Visual Basic Express 2010. I ran it just now in Visual Studio Community 2013 and it works fine there, too.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, Gord.  However, keep in mind it is not the value in VB that is incorrect.  It is the value in Access.  Are you also writing out to an Access table?

Comment: Yes. The test code adds a new row to the DataTable and then writes it to the database via the .Update method of the DataAdapter. The correct value is written to the database when the calculation rounds the value to 2 decimal places. Try running the test code to see for yourself.